# Any way to pass parameters to Global or Object Specific Action Components from a button click?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Assume we have a Lightning component.

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction" >
    <aura:attribute name="test" type="String"/>

    Display dynamic text passed on button click from Global Publisher Layout or Object Specific Layout
    {!v.test}
</aura:component>
enter code here
```

This component is declared as a Global Action (and it is put on Global Publisher layout).
[image]

Also the same component is declared as Object-Specific Action (and it is put on corresponding Object Layout, so the button is visible).
[image]

Is there any way to pass some parameters like current viewed record Id or some other attributes of current record by a button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [it is possible to pass at least RecordId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action_recordid.htm)

The component should implement force:hasRecordId interface and have a property

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
```

Comment: You do not need to declare your own aura:attribute, as force:hasRecordId defines it for you.

Answer (score 1):

To get a record Id you need to implement the force:hasRecordId interface.
One you have done this you can access the record id by: {!v.recordId}